# Passing Jenkins params to build.gradle using groovy pipeline

Tags: jenkins, gradle, groovy

A beginner with groovy pipeline syntax so bear with me.

I have a project in which I am trying to build a declarative groovy pipeline script.

I need to project to be paramterized such that users can pass in a number of variables at runtime. These parameters need to be passed to build.gradle.

If I choose Choice Parameters, so long as the naming convention is maintained, can I pass them as gradle switches to be read in the pipeline?

[image]

Pipeline snippet:

```
try {
    sh "./gradlew clean taskOne -DwhichBrowser=”${browser}” -Denv=${env} -DuserName=${userName} -DpassWord=${password} --continue
} finally { //publish HTML REPORT
```

Or, do I need a separate Choice Params section in my pipeline?

Comment: What i understood from your question is, that you want to know if you can use choice parameter from jenkins job dashboard or you should have parameter section in your pipeline script.. so either one of them you can use, it will work fine.. but it will be good to have in pipeline, so that all the job configuration will be maintained at one place.

Comment: @RohitJindal no, I wasn't asking if/or, I was asking whether parameters passed as Choice Parameters will be passed to the build.gradle at runtime, if used in this way: where the parameters are written as a gradle command issued within the groovy pipeline file

Comment: Ok. Yes it will work.